# segmentation error when accessing a linked list or doing a malloc() on linux

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm having problems with a segmentation fault on a Linux system.
I'm using code from Aho and Ullman's "Foundations of Computer Science" C edition.
This is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct que_element
{
    long mem_address;
    long mem_data;

    int msg;
} Qq;

typedef struct CELL *LIST;
struct CELL
{

    Qq el;

    int element;
    LIST next;
};


Qq l1element;

typedef struct
{
    LIST front;
    LIST rear;
} QUEUE;

main()
{
    QUEUE *l1c2l1d; /*L1 Controller to L1 Data */

    l1c2l1d->front = malloc(sizeof *l1c2l1d);
}
```

Comment: If you want to represent `true`/`false`, use `typedef char BOOLEAN`. ;) `int` usually has 4 bytes on 32-bit, while `char` has always 1 byte.

Comment: @Gandaro But an int is usually faster to access than a `char`.

Comment: Why define your own boolean instead of including [stdbool.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/stdbool.h.html)?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an initializing step I'm missing?

Yes, `l1c2l1d` is uninitialized in your code. Dereferencing it means dereferencing `NULL` (since `l1c2l1d` is global). Try this:

```
l1c2l1d = malloc(sizeof *l1c2l1d);
l1c2l1d->front...
```

#### EDIT In light of last edit

You have this:

> ```
> main()
> {
>     QUEUE *l1c2l1d; /*L1 Controller to L1 Data */
>
>     l1c2l1d->front = malloc(sizeof *l1c2l1d);
> }
> ```

In this case `l1c2l1d` is uninitialized, it points to garbage. Try this (**copy-paste it this time**):

```
main()
{
    QUEUE *l1c2l1d; /*L1 Controller to L1 Data */

    l1c2l1d = malloc(sizeof *l1c2l1d);
    l1c2l1d->front = malloc(*l1c2l1d->front);
}
```

Comment: I just tried l1c2l1d = malloc(sizeof *l1c2l1d) , but it also causes the segmentation error.

Comment: I just tried making defining l1c2l1d in main(), still segmentation error.

Comment: @Mark Something else must be causing it (like your `enqueue` function).

Comment: I removed all of the function definitions (enque, deque, etc.).  I just have main() and the QUEUE and link list definitions.  It still dies on that first line (the malloc).

Comment: I think it's time to punt.  I'll just use an array of structures as my linked list.  Not as fancy but I won't have to worry about malloc().  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Mark No! Edit your question to leave the smallest program that will cause a segfault and I will run it and see what's wrong with it.

Comment: I've shortened the program.  It dies on that first malloc.  This is a RedHat system. CentOS release 5.7 I wonder if the C compiler just isn't implementing pointers correctly.

Comment: @Mark You misunderstood my previous suggestion. I edited my answer.

Comment: Those two malloc()'s did the trick.  Thank you.  It works now.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be going for something along the lines of:

```
main()
{
    QUEUE l1c2l1d = { 0, 0 }; /*L1 Controller to L1 Data */

    l1c2l1d->front = l1c2l1d->rear = malloc(sizeof CELL);
}
```